# Freeing memory in the caller that is reallocated by the callee?

Tags: c, memory, memory-leaks, heap-memory, realloc

Here is my situation:

main allocates memory based on string and calls function by passing an address. The function then appropriately resizes the passed memory to accommodate more data. After which when I try to release the memory I get heap error.

Here is the code:

```
typedef char * string;
typedef string * stringRef;

/**************************
            main
**************************/
int main()
{
    string input = "Mary had";

    string decoded_output = (string)calloc(strlen(input), sizeof(char));
    sprintf(decoded_output, "%s", input);
    gen_binary_string(input, &decoded_output);
    free(decoded_output); /*this causes issue*/

    return 0;
}

void gen_binary_string(string input,stringRef output)
{
    int i=0, t=0;   
    size_t max_chars = strlen(input);   

    /*
        the array has to hold total_chars * 8bits/char.
        e.g. if input is Mary => array size 4*8=32 + 1 (+1 for \0)
    */
    string binary_string = (string)calloc((BINARY_MAX*max_chars) + 1, sizeof(char));

    int offset = 0;

    /* for each character in input string */
    while (*(input+i))
    {       
        /* do some binary stuff... */       
    }

    /* null terminator */
    binary_string[BINARY_MAX*max_chars] = '\0';

    int newLen = strlen(binary_string);
    string new_output = (string) realloc((*output), newLen);
    if (new_output == NULL)
    {
        printf("FATAL: error in realloc!\n");
        free(binary_string);
        return;
    }
    strcpy(new_output, binary_string);

    (*output) = new_output;

    free(binary_string);
}
```

Comment: I suggest that you use the term "passing by address" instead of "passing by reference". C++ has a specific concept of what's a reference, and since C and C++ are somewhat close to each other, it could save you trouble to not use the same word to describe a C concept.

Comment: stop using pointer typedefs, they make the code hard to read

Comment: @zneak I think it is fine to use "pass by reference" as the term applies to many languages;  although you do occasionally run into super-pedants who seem unwilling to admit their ability to know what you are talking about

Comment: sorry Mr.McNabb if my question bothers you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be misunderstanding the purpose of `realloc`.  Calling `realloc` will not necessarily return a newly allocated object.  If possible, it will return the same object, **extended** to hold more bytes.  Also, it automatically copies the object's contents.  Theferore: (1) you should not copy and (2) you should not free the old buffer.

> The `realloc()` function changes the size of the memory block pointed
>   to by `ptr` to `size` bytes.  The contents will be unchanged in the range
>   from the start of the region up to the minimum of the old and new
>   sizes... *(snip)*  Unless `ptr` is `NULL`, it must have been returned by an
>   earlier call to  `malloc()`,  `calloc()`  or  `realloc()`.  If the area
>   pointed to was moved, a `free(ptr)` is done.

---

After a better reading of your code, I don't understand why you're using `realloc` at all here, as you're not using the old contents of `output`.  You'd get the same behaviour (and the same error) if you replaced `realloc` with `malloc`.  I think your real problem is that you're not allocating enough bytes: you should have `strlen(binary_string) + 1` to accommodate the `'\0'` at the end of the string.

Comment: @nickie, thanks for the explanation. This is helping a new person to C pointers like me alot. But I am doing calloc((BINARY_MAX*max_chars) + 1, which should take care of the '\0'. At least that is what I am thinking.

Comment: @KerrekSB but that would cut site traffic by 90%

Comment: No, I mean in the call to `realloc`, you have `newLen = strlen(binary_string)`.  This should be `+1`, because later you're using `strcpy` to copy the `binary_string` there.

Answer (score 1):

A better option would be to pass in a `char**` from the caller, let the callee allocate the `char*` and then pass back the pointer at the end of the function.

This prevents the need for two allocations and one free (always a bad sign).